# how does this initialisation in c works?

Tags: c, initialization, int

```
int a=3,1; 
int b=(5,4);
```

I am a beginner in c and I noticed in a book this type of initialization . what does this `initialisation` mean?

Comment: `int a=3,1;` is not even valid C code, since `=` has higher precedence than `,`.

Comment: [What does the comma operator `,` do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int b = (5,4)` will first evaluate 5 then 4. The last thing that is evaluated will be assigned to the variable. For example

```
int b = (5,4,3,2,1)
```

in this case the value of b will be 1.

Comment: then what is the use of that previous four numbers??